# Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables, $X \text{~} Pois(2), Y \text{~} Pois(3)$. calculate: $P(X + Y \le 1)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Another previous year exam question:

> Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables, $X \text{~}  Pois(2), Y \text{~} Pois(3)$. calculate: $P(X + Y \le 1)$

What is the right way to approach such question?

Mainly stuck because of the sum notations.

I'd be glad for any help and hints, but please not a final answer only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer by heropup gives a clear basic way to get at the probability. For a fancier version, it turns out that the sum of two independent Poisson with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda+\mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super simple hint:  If $X$ and $Y$ are Poisson, then they each can only take on values in $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$.  Therefore, $$\Pr[X + Y \le 1] = \Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 0)] + \Pr[(X = 0) \cap (Y = 1)] + \Pr[X = Y = 0].$$

---

So, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, it follows that $$\Pr[(X = x) \cap (Y = y)] = \Pr[X = x]\Pr[Y = y].$$  Now recall that for a Poisson random variable $X$ with rate parameter $\lambda$, $$\Pr[X = x] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots.$$  For your specific $X$, we would have $\lambda = 2$.  And for $Y$, $\lambda = 3$.  Now using this information, can you calculate $$\Pr[X = 0], \quad \Pr[X = 1], \quad \Pr[Y = 0], \quad \Pr[Y = 1]?$$

Comment: First of all thank you. Sorry for that, can you please remind me what an intersection is related to 2 random variables?

Comment: If I write, for example, $\Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 0)]$, this simply means "the probability that we simultaneously observe the outcomes $X = 1$ and $Y = 0$."

Comment: I really forgot everything in probability .. >.<

Comment: I'm giving up .. I need more help

Comment: Oh I forgot about the independent random variable rule .. here I got it. $5 e^{-5}$ , right? Thanks you so much !!